# AuthScreen component throwing update on unmount warning even though i have a _isMounted check

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-navigation

I'm using Wix react-native-navigation v3, I have an AuthScreen initially that contains listeners for keyboardShow and keyboardHide. And some methods bound to these two that would run a setState.
I also have this AuthView connected to Redux.

Even though I have a _isMounted check, and I see the component going inside the componentWillUnmount method in AuthView, I get the warning whenever I'm on a different screen after being logged in and tapping on a TextInput to show the keyboard. As if this AuthView component is never really unmounted. The stacktrace of the warning indicates that comes from AuthView.js component.

Of course, this warning is the known `"Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component"`

This is what I have on my AuthView.js. All these because I want to hide the footer whenever the keyboard is opened. I'm considering on removing the footer completely.

```
    constructor(super) {
        this._isMounted = true;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this));
        this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this));

        this.setState({
            loading: true
        }, () => {
            this.handleAutoLogin();
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
        this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
        this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
    }

    _keyboardDidShow() {
        if (this._isMounted) {
            this.setState({ footerVisible: false });
        }
    }

    _keyboardDidHide() {
        if (this._isMounted) {
            this.setState({ footerVisible: true });
        }
    }
```

Now, after digging for some info. I read somewhere that if you have a connected component with Redux, it won't really unmount. Is this true? it would be weird. Because I have 2 navigation structures, the ones for login/register/recover account, and the app itself which is a stack-based with bottomTabs. I execute that and the auth view should be completely gone. Why is bothering with warnings from a different "app" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry! I can't believe what it was, it was NOTHING related to what I mentioned above. All this was caused by NativeBase's `<Root>` and `<Toast>` components after carefully checking the stacktrace, it mentioned the Toast component, so I decided to comment out all the code for that and it worked. No more warnings. I have to post this on NativeBase github.